# When running Xamarin.Forms, do I need to add start for appcenter in the shared, iOS and Android projects or just in shared?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The documentation from Microsoft seems unclear and even in the appcenter docs they use the word might when describing what to do.

> "The notes from both the previous sections about iOS and Android apply
>   to Xamarin.Forms as well. If those remarks apply to your application,
>   you **might** need to initialize AppCenter in different places per
>   platform."

Would appreciate advice from others on where I should add this:

```
 AppCenter.Start("iOS= ....
```

Only in shared or in shared, iOS and Android?

Comment: You could call the line in specific platforms ,check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin#4-start-the-sdk

Comment: "You could call"  <  So are you saying it's necessary to call the App.Center.Start in  ALL of the shared, iOS and Android projects or is calling only in the shared project enough? I find the documentation unclear and don't really understand your comment.

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin Forms, need to initialize appcenter tracking service using app secret in shared project only and no change requires on platform projects.

It should be added in OnStart() method of App.xaml.cs class. Analytics or Crashes or both the services can be registered as needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** for Xamarin.Forms, you only need to start AppCenter from App.xaml.cs in `OnStart()` method.

Here's how to enable AppCenter in Xamarin.Forms (excerpted from AppCenter):

> **1. Add NuGet packages to your solution**
>
> Search for “App Center”, and look for the following packages in the
>   results:
>
> 1. If you are on Mac, select **App Center Analytics**, **App Center Crashes**
>      and add both packages.
> 2. If you are on Windows, install **Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics** and
>      **Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes packages**.
>
> If you use the App Center SDK in a portable project, you need to
>   install the packages in both the portable and the Android projects.
>
> **2. Start the SDK**
>
> Open your shared or portable project. Either open `App.xaml.cs` or
>   your class that inherits Xamarin.Forms.Application and add the
>   following using statements:
>
> ```
> using Microsoft.AppCenter;
> using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
> using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
> using Microsoft.AppCenter;
> using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
> using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
> ```
>
> In the same file, add the following in the `OnStart()` method:
>
> ```
> AppCenter.Start("android={Your android App secret here};" +
>                   "uwp={Your UWP App secret here};" +
>                   "ios={Your iOS App secret here}",
>                   typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
> AppCenter.Start("android={Your android App secret here};" +
>                   "uwp={Your UWP App secret here};" +
>                   "ios={Your iOS App secret here}",
>                   typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
> ```
>
> NOTE: You cannot use the same App secret for multiple platforms, right
>   now you will have to create another application in App Center for iOS
>   and UWP and copy the other App secrets in the API call above.